M2 Configurable child produts shown as out of stock on orderconfirmation email
I use M2 version 2.4.5-p1 and I have made some configurable products.
My problem is when a child product is ordered its listed af backorder on the orderconfirmation email even when its in stock.
Why is the stock status not working on the child products of the configurable product?
I have added the child products mannuly to the configurable product when its made.
Its not cool that the stock for the child products are not working and it means it shows the wrong status on frontend becuase I list the salable quantity on the product page.
Hope someone can help me out on this matter :)
Backorder on child product in stock.
Child product listed as not in stock even if it is
